# How to automatically close blank download popup in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, download, popups

When I download a file in Chrome, a blank popup window appears and I have to manually close it each time. Is there a way to have Chrome automatically close this blank window?

Comment: Can you show an example of this issue? I haven't experienced this in Chrome (only blank new tab when opening a `.pdf` file).